# Loop Back to Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to combine these two queries into a single query - just one trip to the database?

Both queries hit the same table, but the first is looking for Total *Active* Circuits, while the second is looking for Total Circuits.

I am hoping to display results like this...
4/15, 12/34, 2/21 (where the first number is ActiveCircuits and the second number is TotalCircuits)

```
SELECT COUNT(CircuitID) AS ActiveCircuits
FROM Circuit
WHERE StateID = 5
AND Active = 1

SELECT COUNT(CircuitID) AS TotalCircuits
FROM Circuit
WHERE StateID = 5
```

Comment: What are the possible values for `Active`? If it's just `0` or `1` then `Sum( Active )` would do the trick. [Suggested reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCircuits,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ActiveCircuits
FROM Circuit
WHERE StateID = 5;
```

This assumes that `CircuitId` is never `NULL`, which seems quite reasonable in a table called `Circuit`.

Comment: Curious why you used `SUM ... ELSE 0`, other options are: dropping the `ELSE` and switching to `COUNT`. I've always used `COUNT` with no `ELSE`, is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @Charlieface . . . I think that `SUM(1)` is much clearer than `COUNT()`.  The issue is that `COUNT(1) = `COUNT(2)` so it seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when to have a `1` wherever it's active and then take the sum to get the total # of 1's or activecircuits.

```
SELECT COUNT(CIRCUITID) AS TOTALCIRCUITS,
SUM(CASE WHEN ACTIVE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ACTIVECIRCUITS
FROM CIRCUIT
WHERE STATEID = 5
```